# how do i send an int to a database in web form

Tags: php, mysql, database, forms, web

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
       $name = $_POST['name'];
       $keywords = $_POST['keywords'];
       $description = $_POST['description'];
       $user_id = $_GET['user_id'];


?>
```

I have a web form that needs to recognize the users id #.  I have it set up where `$user_id = $_GET['user_id'];` I also believe that I have the id retrieval code right.  I made sure that the `user_id` matched my table but I keep getting an error that says that `user_id` is an unidentified index.

Comment: Show us your code please

Comment: We need the query you are using and the structure of your database.

Comment: Why you are using get for user_id and post for the rest??

Answer (score 0):

This means that user_id is not being sent in the headers; You are using both GET and POST in that code snippet, you can only send one at a time when doing a HTTP Request unless your form action has query string in it.

I believe what you could be doing is that on the page with your form, you have user_id set in the URL, however when that form is posted, you will loose all the query strings, so you need to do this;

```
<form action="/post.php?user_id=123" method="POST">
```

That should hopefully solve your issue.

Comment: I don't want to make it a text input I want it to automatically send the users id that is logged in.

Comment: Hi, why are you sending the user_id via GET? You need to add some code in your answer so we understand exactly what you are doing.

Comment: I just edited the post with the code I used for my 4 variables.  I triple checked that they exactly match whats in the database.

Comment: Try what I suggested.

Comment: I'm still having this issue.  If it helps any, in addition to the unidentified index error for the user_id, in the database, the rest of the form submits but the user_id always = 0.

Comment: Try to get user id from session rather than depending on the get or post methods.

Answer (score 0):

did you change user_id retrieval to POST? it should be

```
$user_id = $_POST['user_id'];
```

if it still doesn't work check where you define the user_id for any typo errors.

Answer (score 0):

Okay maybe i figure it out what do you want to point out. Do you want to get the user_id of a user that is already logged-in in your website/webpage, right? If so, then you must use this some code:

```
$_SESSION['user_id'] = $_POST['user_id'];
```

So that you can access the user's id wherever in the page. Hopes this helps.

Comment: This half worked.  I didn't have any more errors but it redirected me to a page called localhost/post.php?user_id=123.  I don't want it to redirect, just to send the user_id with the other info sent in the form.